# nsubstitute mocking a call to a method for any XMLNode value

Tags: .net, mocking, nsubstitute

I have an interface that looks like this

IBasePlugin containig....

```
  bool Connect(XmlNode xmlRequest);
```

I would like to mock this out to return true no matter what request I send in with NSubstitute
Here is what my scenario looks like

```
//[TestFixture]
public class NUnitTest1
{
    //[Test]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var b = Substitute.For< IBasePlugin > ();
        b.Connect(Arg.Any<XmlNode>())
        MyPlugin tester = new MyPlugin(b);
        tester.GetAddressList()

    }
}
```

The issue is, I wondered how I would simulate any value passed to Connect.
I thought it would be something like what I have but it does not like that any call because by ref return type ref T is not supported.    Any input would be great.   Thanks.

Comment: I can't see a type `T` in the definition? From the `IBasePlugin` definition ` b.Connect(Arg.Any<XmlNode>()).Returns(true);` should work.

Comment: What I needed to add was that I was using c# 6.    That answer would have been correct if it was 7.0 or above.   Due to the project, I was not able to convert at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.    You can't use the any. Adding Compat was the key.
I had to use :

```
b.Connect( Arg.Compat.Any<XmlNode>()).Returns(true);
```

Comment: If you prefer you can use the slightly shorter `b.Connect(null).ReturnsForAnyArgs(true)` syntax.